# How to access IDL system variables that starts with '!' with IDL-Python bridge?

Tags: python, idl-programming-language

I am trying to use IDL-Python bridge to call IDL (Interactive Data Language) procedures from Python.
Could anybody tell how to access IDL system variables that starts with '!' from Python? For example, a call in Python

```
from idlpy import *

d2r = IDL.!DDTOR
```

gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: Presumably there is something more this can be tagged with because I have no idea what this question is about solely in the context of Python

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on Stack Overflow. I couldn't fine a tag to IDL(Interactive Data Language). The information about IDL-Python bridge is here: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Python.html

Comment: Where specifically should we be looking for `.!` syntax? I can't say it's wrong but, if there's no tag for what you're using, you need to add some more context I think :)

Comment: I think I found a correct tag: idl-programming-language. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/PythonToIDL.html#SystemVariables:

> To retrieve an IDL system variable such as `!DPI` or `!CONST`, you can use the Python `getattr()` method:
>
> ```
> >>> from idlpy import *
> >>> getattr(IDL, "!dpi")
> 3.1415926535897931
> ```